# Is there a point in registering my company (and my website URL) in a public company catalog for SEO?

Tags: seo, directory, business

There are many local and global company catalogs. Some of them generate info about my company automatically, some have to be manually filled out.

Is there any benefit to registering and adding a link to my site in them? Will I get some juice?

Do these catalogs even have any juice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having links on these catalogs, even if they are low quality, is not always bad. People may find you, learn your company and become direct visitors of the website.

What it is bad, is that you only have links on these catalogs and nowhere else or the links ratio of bad vs good quality is too high.

For example: 
If you have 10 good links and 1500 bad links (catalogue, aggregators etc), this will lead Google to determine that your website is bad quality and spam.

Good link would be an article that a blog/site wrote about your company and put a link to your website

If I were you I would not care about the automatic catalogues that automatically add my website.

What I suggest that you **don't** do, is go and register your website to hundreds or thousands of catalogues and provide link to them from your website. Don't register your website on catalogues where you expect to get zero hits or their content is inrelevant to your website.

Register your website manually on some specific catalogues that you expect to get some hits from there (at least one hit), or exchange some links with blogs or sites relevant to your company.

But dont do it too much.

Comment: Yes, focus efforts on _niche_ directories.

Answer (score 3):

As with any site you need to make sure the directory is not considered a low quality site by Google. If they cannot be found in Google's index, at the very least the links are worthless because Google doesn't know or care about that site. At worst, that site is banned as a low quality site and a link from them is a low quality link. Too many of those and you start to run into trouble with Google.

As far as PageRank goes, PR is per page and most directories pages have virtually no PR. Even worse, you share that PR with every other link on that page. So you get a small piece of almost nothing.

Comment: How can I find out the quality of the site? I don't want to be listed if it can damage me.

Comment: It's hard to know for sure but if they are listed in Google, they are at least good enough not to be banned.